# Can achievement progress be displayed in the HUD, like in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: achievements, counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

In Team Fortress 2 (another Valve-created Source Engine game), there's a menu in-game to display the achievements one has earned. There is also a function to display specific achievements on the HUD.

Is this in Counter-Strike: GO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The only way the player is notified of achievement progress is via those little messages that appear on his or her screen when he or she actually unlocks one.